# How to scrape Full Name from site using Selenium on Python?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I am pretty new to coding and learning Selenium Webdriver on Python. I have had a lot of help up to this point and I am very close to my desired output.

So far I am able to grab the players Abbreviated Names, the Over/Under data, and the Lines. For example,
my current output looks like this:

```
Player                              Over       Line       Under

A. Radulov                          +127       2.5         -167  
G. Landeskog                        -130       2.5         +100
etc.
```

I would, however, like the final output to show all of the player's Full Names:

```
Player                               Over        Line       Under

Alexander Radulov                     +127       2.5         -167  
Gabriel Landeskog                     -130       2.5         +100
etc.
```

Here is my current code

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.betonline.ag/sportsbook/player-props")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"builder")))
time.sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//li[@class='one-third one-third-remove']//a[./b[contains(.,'Over / Under')]]"))).click()
time.sleep(2)




WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[ng-if='selected.league']"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//li[@ng-repeat='league in leagues']/a[.//span[text()='NHL']]"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[ng-if^='selected.game']"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//li/a[.//div[text()='All Available']]"))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(.,'Shots on goal')]"))).click()



player=[]
Over=[]
line=[]
Under=[]
Playersname=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='div-table__row__cell hard--bottom hard--right ng-scope']//a[@class='ng-binding']")))
for players in Playersname:
    player.append(players.text)

OverAndUnder=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a>b.milli.caps.ng-binding")))
count=int(len(OverAndUnder)/2)
x=0
for i in range(count):
    Over.append(OverAndUnder[x].text)
    Under.append(OverAndUnder[x+1].text)
    x=x+2

lines=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[ng-class*='overUnder']>b")))
for l in lines:
    line.append(l.text)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Player":player,"Over":Over,"Line":line, "Under":Under})
print(df)
```

In order to find the Full name I clicked on a player's name and inspected the data. I did find the correct data but I am not sure how to correctly parse this correctly.

[image]

My hope is that the final output will include all of the same data with the exception being the player's full names instead of the abbreviated first names. Thank you in advance for any help or insight that you may offer.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the `innerHTML` of the element:

```
for player_name in Playersname:
    player.append(player_name.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

This will get all the html/text that is inside the element, which in this case is only the player name.

Comment: Thank you @Brydenr for taking the time to explain about innerHTML. I am not sure how to update my code to get the proper output, though. If this is an easy fix for you perhaps you can help. I will start to work on this new update to see if I can figure it out. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to extract the text **98.72** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "player-stats-content.ng-isolate-scope[data='pStats']>p span:nth-of-type(2)"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//player-stats-content[@class='ng-isolate-scope' and @data='pStats']/p[@class='text--center beta cap']//following::span[2]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you sir for you response @DebanjanB! Would you by chance know how to update my code? I am not sure exactly where to implement this new line. I will try, though. Thanks! =)

Comment: @AbleArcher I didn't debug through the steps you coded exactly. I have simply given you the line of code which will print **Alexander Radulov**, once you are on the exact page and the full name is visible on the screen.